# Android: Procedure for Generating Debug build apk's and Release build apk's in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, apk, release

In Android Studio, There is two ways of generating APK's - i.e Debug build Apk and Release Build Apk.
Now Question is how to generate TWO kind of Apk's?

This Question is helpfull to Freshers Android Developers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debug Build APK:**

**Generating Debug build Apk's in android studio consists following steps-**

*Step 1:*
Open the project which is developed by android studio and Click on " Build Variants" which is present in Left buttom corner of the Android Studio. As shown in Below Image.

[image]

*Step 2:*
Select Debug Option in the list. List contains only two i.e Debug and Release.
As shown in below image.

[image]

*Step 3:* To Run Android Application, You will get Debug APK's in the below path of the project

```
YourProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk\XXXXXX.apk
```

**Release Build APK:**

**Generating Release build Apk's in android studio consists following steps-**

*Step1:*  Open android studio . Build -> Generate Signed APK… . now click on “Generate Signed APK”.

[image]

*Step2:*

[image]

Click Create new.

*Step3:*

Fill the details and click ok.

jks key details,It will go back to previous window.

[image]

Click Next, and give the password which you stored in key.

*Step4:*

[image]

Now click Finish and wait to complete the building process.

[image]

Now apk generated successfully. Click show in Explorer.

[image]

If you need more details please visit and check the live demo http://javaant.com/how-to-make-apk-file-in-android-studio/#.VwzedZN96Hs

Comment: Thanks for information . But this answer too old . Same type of presents in #so already

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I agree... but some times they will get an idea in one question(Who will read this question) instead of two. :)